# Problema con combobox seleccionando los Index c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, combobox

Bueno pasa lo siguiente tengo 2 `ComboBox` con nombres de países entonces digamos lo siguiente **un viaje de España a Alemania vale 800000 viceversa vale lo mismo** entonces yo lo tengo así

```
if(combo1.Selectedindex==1 && combo2.SelectedIndex==2 ||
    combo1.Selectedindex==1 || combo2.SelectedIndex==2)
{
    //aca lo que va a hacer ,el problema es que solo me da el valor 
    //si selecciono el index 1 y el index 2 pero si pongo index 2 y luego 
    //index 1 me da un valor incorrecto pienso que es en la forma que pongo 
    //que capture los index
}
```

Solo Intento que al seleccionar el índice 1 y 2 o 2 y 1 me mande el mismo valor.

Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que las condiciones Or se comporten como esperas deberías de aislar las condiciones And.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```
if( (combo1.Selectedindex == 1 && combo2.Selectedindex == 2) || 
    (combo1.Selectedindex == 2 && combo2.Selectedindex == 1) )
{
    //do Something
}
```

De esta forma te aseguras que o se cumple una condición u otra.

Comment: Hola antonio gracias por ayudarme lo que me diste funciona en caso que solo fuera digamos una ocasion pero tengo que hacerlo con otros paises tambien entonces son muchos if por asi decirlo no se si exista una solucion mas eficas ,pero al ponerlo digamos 10 veces con otros paises se daña el ejemplo que me diste

Comment: la otra posible solucion seria nuevos if y ponerlos hay la condicion inversa combo=2 combo =1 pero se extenderia mucho

Comment: @user90058 no hay de que, si la cosa se extiende puedes utilizar if_else las veces que necesites. Si mi aporte te ha sido útil espero tu positivo.

Answer (score 0):

Déjame ver si entiendo lo que quieres hacer:

> Combo1   -------- Combo2
>
> España --- a  -----Alemania = "El viaje cuesta 300"
>
> Combo1 --------. Combo2
>
> Alemania --- a -- España = "El viaje cuesta 300"

Entonces supongamos que el contenido de tu primer `ComboBox` el índice **1** es igual a España y el índice **2** a Alemania, tu segundo `ComboBox` tiene el mismo orden.

Si es así entonces en tu condición debe decir así:

```
if(combo1.Selectedindex == 1 && combo2.Selectedindex == 2 || 
combo1.Selectedindex == 2 && combo2.Selectedindex == 1){
    Console.Write("El viaje cuesta 300");
}
```

Entonces si no estoy mal en la condición la lógica es la siguiente 
sí `combobox1` el índice es igual a **1** y en el `combobox2` el índice es igual a **2** o en el `combobox1` el índice es igual a **2** y el `combobox2` el índice es igual a **1** entonces imprime el siguiente mensaje

> Usar **&&** (AND) en una condición **if** es para que ambas condiciones se cumplan y el **||** (OR) es que se pueden cumplir cualquiera de las condiciones escritas.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte amigo pude entender un poco mas ppero me sirvio la respuesta de antonio